# UILocalNotification with Residemenu

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, residemenu

How would one get Local notifications working with a  Residemenu? The goal is once a local notification is clicked upon that it opens up a specific view controller. This view controller is different to the default root view controller. I'm using storyboards with the library so I am not programmatically setting the root view controller in the AppDelegate. However I release in order to get local notifications to work as described above I have to programmatically change the root view controller in

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{
```

I can't find how to do this with RESideMenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add NotificationCenter in you `Residemenu` Class and when Notification comes then Called it. That reload the view and update sidemenu.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];
    }
```

Comment: Has this worked for you? My root is View A but on local notification I want to show View B, not the side menu.

Comment: have you used RESidemen before?